# Exibir palavra maior frequência por linha e calcular quantidade de palavras por linha

Tags: string, ruby, hashmap

Estou com o seguinte texto e tenho que exibir as palavras que aparecem com maior frequência **por linha** e calcular quantidade de palavras de **cada linha**

```
This is a really really really cool experiment really
Cute little experiment
Will it work maybe it will work do you think it will it will
```

O texto acima esta em um arquivo **teste.txt**. Eu abri o arquivo, fiz a leitura dos dados para uma **string** e depois passei para uma **hash**

```
File.foreach ("teste.txt") do |linha|
      a = linha.split
      p a
      b = Hash[a.group_by(&:itself).map { |word, words| [word, words.size]}]
      puts b
    end
```

Tendo feito isso consegui os seguintes resultados (esta intercalado a string com a hash):

```
["This", "is", "a", "really", "really", "really", "cool", "experiment", "really"]
{"This"=>1, "is"=>1, "a"=>1, "really"=>4, "cool"=>1, "experiment"=>1}
["Cute", "little", "experiment"]
{"Cute"=>1, "little"=>1, "experiment"=>1}
["Will", "it", "work", "maybe", "it", "will", "work", "do", "you", "think", "it", "will", "it", "will"]
{"Will"=>1, "it"=>4, "work"=>2, "maybe"=>1, "will"=>3, "do"=>1, "you"=>1, "think"=>1}
```

Nesse ponto estou travado pois não estou sabendo iterar sobre a hash, quando acho a chave e o valor **"really"=>4** da primeira linha não estou conseguindo imprimir a palavra mais frequente da linha de baixo (apesar de todas estarem uma vez). Não sei também se essa é a melhor forma de realizar esse processo, mas foi o que pensei para tentar resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está no caminho certo! Primeiro de tudo precisa agrupar os valores, para isso eu vou utilizar o [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Enumerable/each_with_object).

```
frase = 'hustle hustle talent'
# precisa do split para obter ['hustle', 'hustle, 'talent']
frequencias = frase.split.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |palavra, hash| hash[palavra] += 1 }
```

Até agora vai funcionar como você já está trabalhando. Para saber que palavra tem a maior frequência não é difícil, veja:

```
frequencias.max_by { |key, value| value }
#=> ["hustle", 2]
```

Para imprimir é só armazenar os valores retornado pelo [`Enumerable#max_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max_by). Ele retorna um array com a chave e o valor.

```
maior_ocorrencia = frequencias.max_by { |key, value| value }
puts "A palavra que mais aparece é: #{maior_ocorrencia[0]} (#{maior_ocorrencia[1]})"
```

Daí é só iterar e utilizar essa mesma lógica.

[**Veja funcionando no repl.it**](https://repl.it/repls/TerrificStraightPhoenix). Acho que deu para clarear melhor, qualquer coisa deixa um comentário.